# requireActivity(), requireContext() and requireFragmentManager() wont work with AndroidX

Tags: android, androidx, android-jetifier

I've been working on updating out project which contains DataBinding, to the new AndroidX packages. There were a number of issues with misuse of the DataBinding SafeUnbox methods, but these are resolved and I am currently prevented from building because AndroidX does not seem to support the `requireActivity`, `requireContext` and `requireFragmentManager` methods.

I have `android.enableJetifier=true` and `android.useAndroidX=true` in my gradle properties and have fixed minor issues it presented, but changing from `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` has not been required (thankfully - because libraries like trello.rxlifecycle then break)

**So even though the Fragment and Activity classes/imports are unchanged, I can no longer use the require methods. Is there a fix for this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was experiencing this first with Android Studio 3.1.2. No other build issues were presented. After I did an **upgrade to Android Studio to 3.2** and used the Migrate tool (<kbd>Refactor</kbd> -> <kbd>Migrate to AndroidX</kbd>) I saw other, previously **hidden build issues**. Once these other (hidden) issues were resolved I was able to build the project despite the IDE showing errors with these methods..

Note: even though I can build normally, the calls to requireActivity still show red in Android Studio, so if you see this I encourage you to try to build anyway